# @setup vs background reference in final report

Tags: karate

The [duplicate post reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75870840/possible-bug-v1-3-no-longer-reads-file-references-in-a-scenario-outline) helped me solve the issue, but now I see the setup being counted as a test scenario in 1.3.0. Moving to 1.3.1 has fixed that issue as well, but the @setup reference only shows on the first scenario, and no further entries, along with no background reference, but the background shows in subsequent tests. Is this expected? [image: @setup vs background reference in final report]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The `Background` does not apply to the `@setup` as [explained in the design](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1905#issuecomment-1203597442).

And the `@setup` body will appear only once. It could possibly be duplicated in the report, but right now that's how it is implemented. This should normally not be a concern because the point of the `@setup` is to move some setup logic out of the actual business flow you are testing.

Code contributions are welcome to improve how it works.

Comment: So should the background step appear in the steps list of the first scenario item rather than just the subsequent ones, since I believe it is being executed as a part of the first run itself?

Comment: @mike opened an issue: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2290